# How to present multiple fields of activities in different languages on a simple landing page?

Tags: website-design, language, landing-page

I'm an IT professional working for a larger enterprise in Switzerland. Furthermore, I'm a freelancer (mostly voluntary activities for schools and very small companies) in my home country Germany.

**Both** fields of activities need to be presented on my **personal website**. For the IT professional engagement, some sort of blogging is expected by my employer, which must be written in English.

The voluntary activities are very local activities (only a particular region of Germany), thus it should be written in German.

*Assuming a re-design of my website, how could I combine both offerings and solve the language mix issue here?*

**Thoughts**

I was thinking of a simple, localized landing page, with two "buttons" redirecting a visitor to the field of activities (sub-page/dedicated page or site) written in either English or German.

Of course, I want to share as much as I can, e.g. about me section and the overall theme, but still keep the effort low. No extra translation of content, no fancy language detection.

I'm looking for some real-life examples or other ideas.

Comment: If they don't affect each other, you can work with a home to split audience by what hey are looking for. And if they can't be together, I suggest you to make two complete different websites. See an interestind splited website example: https://www.arenapersonnel.com/. And see a brazilian website as an example: http://mgcestudio.com.br/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, Sebastian! Having read different portfolios of people that encountered the same issue in Spain, I have come up with the conclusion that:

**Multilingual means multicultural.** Which can be great for your portfolio if you treat it correctly. I would mix those languages since you are bilingual, but in the end, I would also tell the visitor that he is about to read English (in case of a German visitor) or German (in case of an international visitor) content and you can explain why is that. Just to try, I would add a little Google translator button in case a visitor wants really to know more about.

Comment: I love your quote:
> "*Multilingual means multicultural*".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the responses here, I developed confidence to mix languages.

As my final solution, I placed a big badge in German language on my simple and lean landing page with an about me text in English language.

Furthermore, I used a German flag/heart icon to indicate, that the mix of languages is by intent. This way I'm able to mix languages even in the footer section for all pages.

**Here is the result:**

[image: Landing page with language mix]

Comment: Looks amazing!!